# How to Hide Parameters of URL in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

`http://localhost:49397/ChildCare/SponsorChild/83`

This is the Link ,which is being generated when i click on action link in table and redirecting to Edit Action, now i want to Hide the number '83' in the URL how can i acheive this,

i am using VS2010 MVc4 Razor,
Sorry for my bad engllish
thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for quick reply ,Can u explain me in detail

Comment: Use POST rather than GET

Comment: Please provide more information, otherwise people have to guess what you want.

Comment: You should not hide them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you work with links, the links send by `GET` request to the server, then the parameters are in the url. Might you have two options:

1 - the parameters would have to be on `data` attributes like `data-id="83"` and then create a form to send data by post, and creating tags `input` with attributes `data-x`, for example:

```
<a href="my/url" data-id="83> link </a>
```

then with javascript you need create the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="my/url">
    <input value="83 name="id" type="hidden" /> 
</form>
```

and run the event with JS form submit like: `jQuery('form').submit()`

2 - you can encrypt and then decrypt get parameters in the controller: [How to encrypt and decrypt data in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15767143/138071)

**Edit**

Example for point one:

Html:

```
<div id="container-generic-form" style="display:none;">
   <form action="" method="POST"></form>
</div>

<a href="my/url" data-id="83" data-other="blue" class="link-method-post">my link</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function() { // document ready

   var controlAnchorClickPost = function(event) {

       event.preventDefault(); // the default action of the event will not be triggered

       var data = $(this).data(), 
           form = $('#container-generic-form').find('form');

       for(var i in data) {

          var input = $('<input />', {
             type: 'hidden',
             name: i
          }).val(data[i]);

          input.appendTo(form);
        }

        form.submit();
   };

   $('a.link-method-post').on('click', controlAnchorClickPost); //jquery 1.7

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, found answer at the given link, i don't how to work with data- attributes.i Used Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() encode , decode methods. thanks again

Answer (score 5):

We use Two pages like that to hide the variable

```
public ActionResult RestoreSavedSession(string id)
    {
        Session["RestoreSavedSession"] = id;
        return RedirectToAction("RestoreSavedSessionValidation");
    }

    public ActionResult RestoreSavedSessionValidation()
    {
        return View("RestoreSavedSessionValidation");
    }
```

You hit `RestoreSavedSession` it then takes parameter stores it locally and calls `RestoreSavedSessionValidation` where it reads parameter from [Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.hpc.scheduler.session.session(v=vs.85).aspx) or [Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx) or whatever.

Comment: this is a nice and simple solution, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I uses a preview method store the route data to TempData, and route it to the correct action.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Preview(string act, string ctl, string obj)
    {
        TempData["Data"] = obj;
        return RedirectToAction(act, ctl);
    }
```

To use it

```
return RedirectToAction("Preview","Controller",new {act="action",ctl="controller",obj=JsonConvet.SerializeObject(obj)});
```

After routing

```
var x=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(TempData["Data"].ToString());
```