# how to encrypt and decrypt url in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am using Model View Controller , How can I encrypt my query string URL for my edit and delete views ?

Comment: There is a whole namespace dedicated to cryptography in .Net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx

Comment: Here's a response from me in which I explain how to encrypt parameters in the URL. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15767143/138071

Answer (score 0):

Not complete answer, but you may build/implement your logic using the technique shown at and my notes below that:

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/21/manipulating-action-method-parameters.aspx/

Additional logic:

Build encryption and decryption methods, which accept values.

While creating the URL/ActionLink, encrypt values using the method and attach value, and while decoding the value, decrypt and set the values to parameters. (using technique mentioned in above link)

You can also refer the project below to implement using URL Rewriting.
https://github.com/sethyates/urlrewriter