# How to pass id to contoller using anchor tag and display only name in the browser url

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a header in my view when I click that header link it should take me to different page. So far it works, but I need to display name in my browser url instead of id like below

//mysite.com/jobs/auto-damage-adjuster-trainee-houston-and-surrounding-cities

instead of

//mysite.com/jobs/id=1234&name=auto-damage-adjuster-trainee-houston-and-surrounding-cities

Right now with my code below it displaying id and name in browser url.

View:

```
 var urlName = @Model.jb_title.Replace(" ", "-").Replace('/', '-').Replace('?', '-').Replace(':', '-');
 <a href="@Url.Action("Jobs", "HomeController", new { id = @id, name = @urlName })" class="hyperlinks"><h6>@Model.jb_title</h6></a>
```

Controller :

```
    public ActionResult Jobs(int? id)
    {

        var allDetails = _db.myTable.Where(p => p.id == newId).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(allDetails);
    }
```

I need id my href to pass to controller to get the other details but I do not want to display id in url. How do I achieve this?

Comment: a simple link in a href tag with issue a GET request to the server which passes data via the url query string. to pass data to the server and not have it appear in the url, you'd need to change to a different HTTP method such as POST and pass the data in the body. In your use case, this isn't a very restful approach however that is more of a design decision.

Comment: if you don't want to show your parameter in url, then instead of `GET` use `POST`. In `POST` data will be in `request body`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i hide ID in URL with asp.net MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005426/how-can-i-hide-id-in-url-with-asp-net-mvc4)

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/2174915/4962985] and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826975/how-to-hide-parameters-of-url-in-mvc4]